# How to add new text line in a file without losing the old content

Tags: c#, file, logging, io

I have a simple `void method` that will write a new line into text file but depends on what I tried all the old content overwrite.

**What I try:**

```
    string NewLogLine = "New value";
    File.WriteAllText("LOG.txt", NewLogLine);
```

**The Problem:**
is the old text file content overrides and replaced by the new added line, **So please how can I fix this issue ?**

Answer (score -1):

```
File.AppendAllText("LOG.txt", string.Format("{0}{1}", "OK", Environment.NewLine));
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.